# I'm Duplicating Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dry

We will have a set of records where the user will select what color they want that section to be.  As you can see I'm duplicating script code so that I can change the colors of a div.  This value will be stored in mysql and retrieved when the user access the page again.   Is there a way to format this code so that it's not duplicated 500 times?  Thank you for your help.  --newbie

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>


        <style type="text/css">
            #full {

            background-color: #ffffff;
            }
        </style>

        <title></title>

        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
            $(window).load(function(){
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    $(".theme").change(function()
                    {var background = $("#color1").val();   
                        $("#full").css("background-color", background);
                    });
                    $(".theme2").change(function()
                    {var background = $("#color2").val();   
                        $("#full2").css("background-color", background);
                    });
                    $(".theme3").change(function()
                    {var background = $("#color3").val();   
                        $("#full3").css("background-color", background);
                    });
                });

            });//]]> 

        </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/color_picker.css" type="text/css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorpicker.js"/></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Run the code when document ready
        $(function() {    
            $('#color1').colorPicker({showHexField: false});
            $('#color2').colorPicker({showHexField: false});

        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <body >
        <label for="color">Color :</label> </td><td>
        <div id="full"> 
            <form method="post" action="">

                <input id="color1" type="hidden" name="color1" value="" class="theme"/>
            </div>
            <div id="full2" border="1" width="100%"> 
                <input id="color2" type="hidden" name="color2" value="" class="theme2"/>
            </div>
            <div id="full3" border="1" width="100%"> 
                <input id="color3" type="hidden" name="color3" value="" class="theme3"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: jQuery uses css selectors! But it looks like you have a different theme for each id, why not loop through however many there are and just do something like `$('.theme' + i).change(...);`?

Comment: Your HTML elements aren't nested propertly Shouldn't `<div id="full">` be inside `<form>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using Id's, you can use classes like `full` and `theme`, so your html for any given set would look like

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="full"> 
        <input id="color1" type="hidden" name="color1" value="" class="theme"/>
    </div>
    <div class="full" border="1" width="100%"> 
        <input id="color2" type="hidden" name="color2" value="" class="theme"/>
    </div>
    <div class="full" border="1" width="100%"> 
        <input id="color3" type="hidden" name="color3" value="" class="theme"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then your javascript would look like

```
$('.theme').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var background= $this.val();

    $this.closest('.full').css("background-color", background);
})
```

edit: fixed bug, changed from parent to closest so that `.full` doesn't have to be a direct parent of the input.

Comment: is there a way I can loop this as well?
   $(function() {   
  
   $('#color1').colorPicker({showHexField: false});
   $('#color2').colorPicker({showHexField: false});
   $('#color3').colorPicker({showHexField: false});
   $('#color4').colorPicker({showHexField: false});
   $('#color5').colorPicker({showHexField: false});
   
  });

Comment: @Bobby have you tried `$('.theme').colorPicker({showHexField: false})`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).
If the number of colors is not static you can use the [jquery "starts with" selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to get all of the elements and then take the length.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //if the count is static you can just hardcode it
        var colorCount = $("[id^='color']").length; 

        for(var i = 1; i <= colorCount; i++) {
            var color = "#color" + i;
            var full = "#full" + i;
            var theme = ".theme" + i;

            //only necessary because your first div does not have the number
            if(i === 1) {
                full = "#full";
                theme = ".theme";
            }

            $(".theme").change(function()
            {
               var background = $(color).val();   
               $(full).css("background-color", background);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Below is a working snippet. There were some issues with your HTML, and I'm not sure if you were setting the [`.change()` event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) intentionally, but for the demo I just changed it directly.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var colorCount = $("[id^='color']").length; 
        
        for(var i = 1; i <= colorCount; i++) {
            var color = "#color" + i;
            var full = "#full" + i;
            var theme = ".theme" + i;

            //only necessary because your first div does not have the number
            if(i === 1) {
                full = "#full";
                theme = ".theme";
            }
            
            var background = $(color).val();   
            $(full).css("background-color", background);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.color-box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 2px black;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<label for="color">Color :</label>
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="full" class="color-box"> 
        <input id="color1" type="hidden" name="color1" value="lightblue" class="theme"/>
    </div>
    <div id="full2" class="color-box"> 
        <input id="color2" type="hidden" name="color2" value="#226666" class="theme2"/>
    </div>
    <div id="full3" class="color-box"> 
        <input id="color3" type="hidden" name="color3" value="rgba(140,15,110,.6)" class="theme3"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I'd like for it to change the color when they pick a color.  This only loads the color.